# Practicing loops

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to improve my function writing skills and I'm a little confused on the proper structure of functions. I've searched a ton of examples, but none are that clear to me. My aim is to run the `#RUN over and over` section in a `for` loop and build a function which allows me to control the number of times I can loop it.

Currently, I've got to this point:

```
set.seed(123)
#Start but setting the conditions and being the Win Lose counters 
Count_Win_Hunt=0 
Count_Win_Moose=0 

#RUN over and over
Hunter=1
Moose=7
win=0

while(win != 1){ a = sample(1:6, 1) # dice roll 
if( a<= 4) {Moose = Moose+a} else{Hunter = Hunter+a}
if( Hunter >= Moose  ) { Count_Win_Hunt = Count_Win_Hunt +1 } else if( Moose >= 12) {Count_Win_Moose = Count_Win_Moose + 1}

if( Hunter >= Moose || Moose >= 12 ) {win = win+1} else {
  #if not condition not meet roll again
  a = sample(1:6, 1) # dice roll
  if( a<= 4) {Moose = Moose+a} else{ Hunter = Hunter+a}}}


# calculated the average win rates 
paste0( round(Count_Win_Hunt/(Count_Win_Hunt+Count_Win_Moose),4)*100,"%"," of the time the Hunter won")
paste0( round(Count_Win_Moose/(Count_Win_Hunt+Count_Win_Moose),4)*100,"%"," of the time the Moose won")
```

Comment: What is your specific problem? What works, what does not? Is your code complete and needs review (then code review SE might be a better fit) or do you have errors which you could share?

Comment: So I think that I've got the correct system in place to calculate the percentage, and I've done it on paper. I think that the first two `if` statements work. I'm having trouble getting the `for` loop to run within the function.

I get this error:
 `Error: unexpected '+' in:
"  for(val in c(1:4))
    probability + function(hunter,goose+"`.


I've never heard of code review SE, so I'll check that out.

Comment: You are adding a list to a float, which simply does not work (hence unexpected ```+```, because you cannot calculate these variables). See my pointers for overall structure improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Besides my general problems with your question (please be more specific as to your actual problem) your for-loops have a wrong syntax. They should be like this:

```r
for (val in sequence)
{
statement
}
```

So applied to your function they should look like this:

```r
for (val in c(1:4))
{
probability + (hunter,goose+val,num+1)
}

for (val in c(5:6))
{
probability + (hunter,goose+val,num+1)
print probability
}
```

However the are not only syntactically wrong, also their content seems to be wrong.

E.g. in your second for-loop, the goose steps forward even though it should be the hunter. Also these are not two for-loops but should be an if-statement like this:

```
if (val <= 4) {
probability + (hunter,goose+val,num+1)
}
else {
probability + (hunter+val,goose,num+1)
}
```

Finally the whole structure of your function seems strange (and has misleadingly named variables). Shouldn`t it be something like this:

```
dice_roll <- function(hunter,goose, win){
# While to check for winning condition
while(win != 1){
 dice_roll = sample(1:6, 1) # simulate dice roll

 # If statement depending on dice roll, increasing value of hunter or goose by dice roll

 # Change win condition
 If(hunter >= goose){
  win <- 1
 }
}

dice_roll(1,7,0)
```

Comment: Cheers that makes sense, I'll have another go at it.

Comment: So I think I' managed it. The `while` function really helped, so thanks @Fnguyen.  `set.seed(123)
#Set the conditions
Count_Win_Hunt=0 
Count_Win_Moose=0 
Hunter=1
Moose=7
win=0

while(win != 1){ a = sample(1:6, 1) 
if( a<= 4) {Moose = Moose+a} else{Hunter = Hunter+a}
if( Hunter >= Moose  ) { Count_Win_Hunt = Count_Win_Hunt +1 } else if( Moose >= 12) {Count_Win_Moose = Count_Win_Moose + 1 }

if( Hunter >= Moose || Moose >= 12 ) {win = win+1} else {
  #if not condition not meet roll again
  a = sample(1:6, 1) # dice roll
  if( a<= 4) {Moose = Moose+a} else{ Hunter = Hunter+a}}}`

Comment: @pr1g11 Happy to help! Please remember however that SO aims to have answered question help everyone in the future, so it is discouraged to change the initial question. I would recommend to reinsert the original "wrong code" and simply add your new code as an update at the end of the post. This way future users looking for the answer will know whether they had a similar problem.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll restate my original code. Is there any way of running my new code as a loop? To simulate like 100 games? Thanks!

Comment: @pr1g11 I would package your current code in a function and loop over that function with   ```replicate(100,myfunction)```